# (Java) The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object error

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

The following code:

```
// Adds game button container
Object[][] gameButtons = new Object[3][3];

// Adds game buttons to game button container
Arrays.fill(gameButtons, new JButton[3][3]);
for (int i = 0; i < gameButtons.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < gameButtons[i].length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
                gameButtons[i][j][k][l] = new JButton();******
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is throwing me an error:
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object. How do I initialize the JButtons?

EDIT: I forgot to clarify. The error was thrown at the line ******
      Note that the ****** was not in my code.
EDIT 2: I tried Logan's fix, but it still didn't work:

```
for (Object[] row : gameButtons)
        Arrays.fill(row, new JButton[3][3]);
for (int i = 0; i < gameButtons.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < gameButtons[i].length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
                gameButtons[i][j][k][l] = new JButton();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Same error, same place.

Comment: Which line number? I’m assuming `Arrays.fill()`.

Comment: try: Arrays.fill(gameButtons, new JButton());

Comment: @TheGuest not quite — it’s a two-dimensional array

Comment: You have you pass a one-dimensional array, since you are trying to fill a two-dimensional array.

Comment: @Logan What? Please clarify.

Comment: @Raymo111 your array is a two-dimensional array. `Arrays.fill()` only works with one-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @Raymo111 I am not sure why you use gameButtons[i][j][k][l] = new JButton(); than gameButtons[i][j] = new JButton(); Because gameButtons is 3x3 array and I believe thats where u get error

Comment: @Logan How then do I fill a 2d array?

Comment: @Raymo111 a two-dimensional array is just an array of one-dimensional arrays, so you have to fill it one dimension at a time.

Comment: @The Guest I did so because I need a 4D array, but by the 2nd dimension the 2D array of JButtons needs to be changed to a JPanel.

Comment: @Logan Alright then, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Raymo111 no problem.

Comment: @Logan What you told me to do didn't work, the same error is being thrown.

Comment: @Raymo111 can you update the post with your code?

Comment: @Raymo111 you’re trying to fill the row with a two-dimensional array. Also be careful with the use of the enhanced for loop, which is read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gameButtons[i][j]` is of type `Object`, which cannot be indexed as an array. You must first cast it to a `JButton[][]` type:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gameButtons.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < gameButtons[i].length; j++) {
        // cast it to an array type before accessing
        JButton[][] subArray = (JButton[][])(gameButtons[i][j]);

        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
                subArray[k][l] = new JButton();
    }
}
```

Comment: First part was right but I did it in one statement.

Comment: @Raymo111 can you explain what you mean by that? Wasn't your code failing to compile?

Comment: It was. But I only changed the casting part, and it worked out fine. I did in fact mean to populate it with the same instance and the same reference.

Comment: @Dogsdontmeow, if you edit the post to leave just the first part, which answered my question, I'll accept it as the right answer.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need a for loop. If I understand your problem correctly, you can do like this:

```
        //create a sub array
        Object[][] subArray = new Object[3][3];

        // create game button container
        Object[][] gameButtons = new Object[3][3];            

        // Adds buttons to sub array
        Arrays.fill(subArray, new JButton[3][3]);

        // Adds sub array to game button container
        Arrays.fill(gameButtons, subArray);
```

Comment: `Arrays.fill()` expects a one-dimensional array for the first parameter. This is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) helped me a lot with this.

You could also use a GUI maker such as the one in NetBeans IDE it's much simpler than writing the code yourself.

Comment: You didn't actually help me solve the problem, just pointed me to a tutorial.